# how to displaying two tables with no duplicate rows in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have two tables and its data is as below
Advance & Expense

For the emp code expense is repeated. I want expense displayed only once against each emp code, not to repeat for same emp code.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the join on the tables for the report. Go to Database Expert > Links

Also can you go to Database > Show SQL and then see what is causing the 
duplication. Might be as simple as adding one more condition in the Join.

If its genuine duplicate in the table itself then you can also suppress at the detail level by going to Section expert and for the details select suppress duplicates

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can just enable the option `Select Distinct Records` from Database menu  option